# jQuery: how to add onlick event to a dynamic generated div?

Tags: jquery

I want to add a onclick event to a div which generated using folowing code:

```
$("<div />").attr("city", $(this).attr("city"))
            .attr("state", $(this).attr("state"))
            .html($(this).attr("city") + ',' + $(this).attr("state"))
            .appendTo($('#cityList'));
```

Should I write onlick event in html()?

Comment: Why not .bind() it directly after .appendto() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not split up the creation of the div and the chaining of the rest of the code.  For example

```
var elem = $('<div />');
elem.click(function () { 
  // Click handler
});

elem.attr("city", $(this).attr("city"))
    .attr("state", $(this).attr("state"))
    .html($(this).attr("city") + ',' + $(this).attr("state"))
    .appendTo($('#cityList'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the .live() function, which lets you bind events even to elements that are added later dynamically.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

you can [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) click event to `#cityList`

```
$("#cityList").delegate("div","click",function(e){    
//handler code here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bXtEz/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cityList div').live('click', function(){
    ...do stuff;
});
```

[jQuery Live Link](http://api.jquery.com/live/)